# How to open a BottomNavigationView menu item in an activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity, it has a button that I need to take the user to the main activity in the specific menu item

Activity
[image: Image of the activity in which the user is]

when you click cancel it needs to go here in the item "cobrar"
[image]

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
    }
}
```

Click event

```
btnCancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by simply adding finish();

```
btnCancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               finish();
                //startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
```

He automatically went back to where he was, which for now solves my problem